# Repeating regex pattern in Python

Tags: python, regex

I have a file with millions of retweets – like this:

```
RT @Username: Text_of_the_tweet
```

I just need to extract the username from this string.
Since I'm a total zero when it comes to regex, sometime ago here I was advised to use

```
username = re.findall('@([^:]+)', retweet)
```

This works great for the most part, but sometimes I get lines like this:

```
RT @ReutersAero: Further pictures from the #MH17 crash site in  in Grabovo, #Ukraine #MH17 - @reuterspictures (GRAPHIC): http://t.co/4rc7Y4…
```

I only need "ReutersAero" from the string, but since it contains another "@" and ":" it messes up the regex, and I get this output:

```
['ReutersAero', 'reuterspictures (GRAPHIC)']
```

Is there a way to use the regex only for the first instance it finds in the string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a regex like this:

```
RT @(\w+):
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/iZ9yH2/1)**

[image]

**Match information:**

```
MATCH 1
1.  [4-15]  `ReutersAero`
MATCH 2
1.  [145-156]   `AnotherAero`
```

You can use this **python** code:

```
import re
p = re.compile(ur'RT @(\w+):')
test_str = u"RT @ReutersAero: Further pictures from the #MH17 crash site in  in Grabovo, #Ukraine #MH17 - @reuterspictures (GRAPHIC): http://t.co/4rc7Y4…\nRT @AnotherAero: Further pictures from the #MH17 crash site in  in Grabovo, #Ukraine #MH17 - @reuterspictures (GRAPHIC): http://t.co/4rc7Y4…\n"

re.findall(p, test_str)
```

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to use the regex only for the first instance it finds in the string?

Do not use `findall`, but `search`.